# String query error

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2005, ms-access-2003

I make a query in coding. But I got conversion error. Please check my fault.

My query is below

```
        Dim strSelect As String = ""

        strSelect = "SELECT " & _                                            
                    "Description As [Desc], " & _
                    "iif(CurCons = 0, " - ", CurCons) As [CCQty] " & _
                    "FROM tblCur"
```

Exception error is like

> Conversion from string "iif(CurCons =
>   0, " to type 'Double' is not valid

Acturally, in my report, i wanna show if it's zero then '-'. If i set it in this string. I got another error like below

> The provider could not determine the
>   Decimal value. For example, the row
>   was just created, the default for the
>   Decimal column was not available, and
>   the consumer had not yet set a new
>   Decimal value.

From da.Fill

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(strDynamic, m_DBConn)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds, "tblCur")
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strSelect = "SELECT " & _                                            
            "Description As [Desc], " & _
            "IIF(CurCons = 0 OR ISNULL(CurCons), ' - ', CStr(CurCons)) As [CCQty] " & _
            "FROM tblCur"
```

You are still in the SQL Query when you are doing the IIF statement, so you do not want to use the **"** characters for strings, instead you will use **'**.

Your report would need the field where the value is outputted to be set to the Text type, otherwise you will see an error.

Comment: Yes, in coding, it should be single quote. Firstly I got confused where it made data type matching. Now I also set 'IIF ({dtDynamic.CCQty} = "0", " - ", {dtDynamic.CCQty})' in report at Display string of Format Object. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

You are using double quotes to quote the string as well as to quote `"-"`. This will not work because it closes the string, so the dash is interpreted literally as a subtraction operator. You should try something like:

```
"iif(CurCons = 0, '-', CurCons) As [CCQty] " & _
```

This uses single quotes for the dash.